# Strange JavaScript Expression

Tags: javascript

Sometimes, when reading Code written by others, I come across lines of code that I do not understand, for example this one:

```
 var acceptBtn = document.getElementById('saveBtn');
 (acceptBtn) && (acceptBtn.disabled = false);
```

What exactly is the  meaning of the second line and why is it abbreviated like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a strange syntax, but it's shorthand for:

```
if(acceptBtn)
    acceptBtn.disabled = false;
```

I would personally never use it, though.. Bad readability.

Answer (score 3):

It's shorthand for "if `acceptBtn` is not "falsy", then set it's `disabled` property to `false`".

ie:

```
if(acceptBtn){
    acceptBtn.disabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Not just `null` values, but anything that evaluates to `false` through type coercion. So `0`, `undefined`, `""`, etc

Answer (score 2):

The second line takes advantage of the fact that boolean operations in Javascript short-circuit, that is to say if the first part evaluates false then the second part never executes.

It also takes advantage of the fact that javascript can use truthy/falsey values in boolean expressions.

Therefore the second line says, that if `acceptBtn` is falsey (possibly: null or undefined) then go no further, otherwise set the `disabled` property to false.

It stops javascript running in to the equivalent to a null-reference exception.